I'm having an issue with jda plugin development minecraft plugin
I'm getting this error in mven plugin development minecraft plugin:

/home/DiscordLoggerPrivate/src/main/java/com/example/discordlogger/DiscordLoggerPrivate.java:[11,36] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class TextChannel
[ERROR] location: package net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities

I'm creating a plugin, and getting this package error.
Here's my main java code
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDABuilder;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.TextChannel;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter;
import javax.security.auth.login.LoginException;
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;

public class DiscordLoggerPrivate extends JavaPlugin im>

    private TextChannel consoleLogChannel;
    private TextChannel userMessageChannel;
    private TextChannel privateMessageChannel;
    private TextChannel commandLogChannel;

